# Support of Power profile in LinuxPTP

Tags: ptp

Does LinuxPTP Application Stack supports Power profile? as it is not mentioned in the LinuxPTP Project page (reference page for Linux PTP application)

Linux PTP reference page: http://linuxptp.sourceforge.net/

Comment: You have to check Ubuntu packages from https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=LinuxPTP by yourself.

Comment: Hii, not able to get information regarding PTP profile in the distribution from given link. Please help.